# Custom Navigation is visible on Pop up windows like add document etc in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

> I have created a custom navigation in masterpage. I am facing an issue
>   as this navigation is also visible on pop up windows like add
>   document, add announcements etc. How can I make it visible only on
>   pages in site collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too solve your problem

All you need to do to hide custom elements from the popup windows, add the `s4-notdlg` class to your custom element div:

In your case its Navigation

> <div class=”custom-Navigation-class s4-notdlg”>  <div>